# Как задать класс css для каждого элемента цикла foreach?

Tags: php, циклы, foreach

Не нашёл ничего по вопросу - как задать класс css для каждого элемента цикла foreach?
Сильно не ругайте если что не так-я новичок в пхп. Пример цикла:

```
<?foreach($pages as $item):?>
    <div class="nav_v2"><a href=""><?=$item['title'];?></a></div>                          
<?endforeach;?>
```

Необходимо задать для каждого элемента (div) свой класс для последующего использования в css. Ничего на ум не приходит по этому поводу толкового.

Comment: Покажи, как оно должно выглядеть в HTML после того

Comment: <div class="nav_v2 CLASS_NAME"><a href=""><?=$item['title'];?></a></div> 

не?

Comment: Задумка такая-в этом цикле выводятся пункты горизонтального меню на сайте...я хочу присвоить каждому пункту свой класс css...это делаю для того ,чтобы после с помощи jquery сделать плавную смену background при наведении...вот и всё...не могу понять как это в принципе делается...получается что можно задать класс для всех пунктов меню...а для каждого отдельно-разный?как сделать ?подскажите...
Говоря простыми словами-
<div class="nav_v2"><a href="">Главная</a></div>;
<div class="nav_v3"><a href="">Контакты</a></div>;
<div class="nav_v4"><a href="">О себе</a></div>

Comment: Не поймите неправильно,я не лентяй там какой-нить и не хочу получить просто решение...хотя бы направьте в правильное русло...

Comment: заводить отдельный класс на каждый элемент глупо.

Comment: глупо было бы-если бы не нужно было потом через этот класс задать разный бэкграунд при наведении через jquery...я же чётко всё расписал...прошу не флудить и отвечать по-существу если можно...

Comment: Вы немножко не поняли наверное)
Вот смотрите-я хочу чтобы пункт меню "Главная" при наведении менял цвет фона допустим с красного на оранжевый, а пункт меню "Контакты" с зелёного на синий...это можно сделать только задав разные классы)никак иначе)или на php писать что-то типа if <?=$item['title']?> равно то-то, то вывести стиль такой-то))

Comment: Можно взять за class какое-нибудь значение из базы и с помощью функций php можно привести (если нужно) это значение к виду класса. Если подходящих значений на английском нет, то возьмите и сделайте в базе новое поля для класса и тогда вы сможете задать любой класс для любого пункта меню.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?
    $i = 0;
    foreach($pages as $item):
?>
  <div class="nav_v2_<?=$i; $i++;?>">
    <a href="">
      <?=$item['title'];?>
    </a>
  </div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

**И тогда у вас будут классы nav_v2_0, nav_v2_1 и т.д.**

После, в `css` делайте, что хотите:)

```css
.nav_v2_0 {
  background: blue;
}

.nav_v2_1 {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо div нужно выводить li. Ul обьявить перед циклом и после цикла закрыть. После этого ты сможешь обращаться к любому элементу в CSS через li:nth-child(тут вписываешь порядковый номер своей li).