# Создание цикла для вывода контейнера с классом

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Нужно создать функцию чтобы получилось вот такой в цикле:

```
<div class="parts_holder">
<div class="part1"></div>
<div class="part2"></div>
<div class="part3"></div>
<div class="part4"></div>
<div class="part5"></div>
</div>
```

Чтобы для каждого цикла было присвоено класс `part` а нумерование было автоматов начиная с `1`.

Comment: Нужна вот такая конструкция, но то что там описано не работает. Вот   [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/324294/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-css-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function func_name($parts){
    $content = '<div class="parts_holder">';
    for ($i=1; $i <= count($parts); $i++) { 
        $content .= '<div class="part'.$i.'"></div>';
    }
    $content .= '</div>';
    return $content;
}
```